# Performance of BitmapImage vs. ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, image, performance, xaml

I tried searching around but I couldn't find an answer to this question: are there performance improvements in using an ImageBrush to fill a rectangle rather than creating a BitmapImage and setting its source property?

I have to render an high number of images (we are trying to push over 5000), and for now I'm creating them this way:

```
<Image x:Name="img" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"
    Source="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource string}}" >
</ext:IdImage>
```

and in the converter:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri(value as String);
image.DecodePixelWidth = int.Parse((String)parameter);
image.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.EndInit();
return image;
```

NB: I have to use the converter to set the DecodePixelWidth property.

Using an ImageBrush I could freeze the brush thus, according to what I read, increasing the performance so I was wondering if I should change the way I build the images.

P.S. The Images are not static but are translated around.

Comment: The low speed when rendering the image? 
I's slow either using BitmapImage that ImageBrusch?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not"

Comment: Why don't you implement a performance benchmark yourself? just sayin' ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not in the code but in the architecture WPF.

If your problem is performance, for my personal experience developing XAML is necessary that the pc is preferably provided with a dedicated video card. However, many times even in very old pc with windows XP to thin the program I did install the updates direct X library

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179113/en

XAML is based on directX

Try it and let me know